# OwnCloud-client 2.1.1 crashes: Aborted (Core dumped)

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, xfce, owncloud-client

The last output of...

```
owncloud --logfile <home/username/filename>
```

...is:

```
ASSERT: "!_runningNow" in file /usr/src/packages/BUILD/src/libsync/owncloudpropagator.cpp, line 669 aborted core dumped owncloud
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I did this

– Uninstall owncloud-client using software centre

– Delete temporary files and directories whose names begin with sni-qt *, in /tmp 
– Erase the $/.local/share/data/ownCloud (it contains the connection and configuration data from the previous version).
– Reinstall owncloud-client

To see the .local directories go to the file manage and press ctrl H to see the hidden directories.

I got this fix from https://wayneoutthere.com/weird-bug-fix-for-crashing-owncloud-client-on-ubuntu-14-04segmentation-fault-core-dumped/

It has worked for me. good luck